# Why am I getting the error in post? Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, api

So I'm trying to create a simple REST API using Laravel. 
While testing out the API with creating new items to the database I'm receiving an error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`world`.`cities`, CONSTRAINT `cities_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CountryCode`) REFERENCES `country` (`Code`)) (SQL: insert into `cities` (`Name`, `CountryCode`, `District`, `Population`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Valhalla, vlh, Ragnar Alley, 200000000, 2020-02-19 01:07:26, 2020-02-19 01:07:26)) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 669

here's the Controller:

```
      public function createCity(Request $request) {
        $city = new City;
        $city->Name = $request->Name;
        $city->CountryCode = $request->CountryCode;
        $city->District = $request->District;
        $city->Population = $request->Population;
        $city->save();
```

Model:

```
class City extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cities';

    protected $fillable = ['Name', 'CountryCode', 'District', 'Population'];
}
```

Help would be appreciated as I can't figure out why I'm getting the error after POST.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: CountryCode  must be exist in your country table?

can you show your table structur?

Comment: Does `vhl` exists in your `country` table `Code` column?

Comment: I only have the cities table. I've been given an sql file to work with and it only has one table.

Answer (score 0):

You try to add `vlh` as `contry_code` value into your model .but this field refrence to another model that have `country` name and in that table there is not any record with this condition and `vlh` value is unknown or it.

You can romve relation between these models (if it is possible) or first find the `id` of `country` that has `that code` and then insert it into your model.

Comment: Thanks! But that's the thing. I have only one table in the SQL file and no reference to county code anywhere. I should mention that the country code is not a simple string as it shown on the database, but more like a link. In any case I don't have any other table to pull info from.